# Flutter Failed assertion: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true. in slider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, flutter-slider

I want to get the dynamic data from the database to the slider value.
But firstly it gives me the error of value type double so I convert my string data to double and now it gives me the error of.
`Failed assertion: line 147 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.`.
Please help me with how to solve this error.
where I can define the min-max value which comes from database

value comes from databse:- `17.00`  in `data[0]['distance']`

Here is my code:-

```
class Editprofile extends StatefulWidget {

Editprofile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
_Editprofile createState() => _Editprofile();
}


class _Editprofile extends State<Editprofile>{

 var UsrID = Auth.prefs?.getString('usrid');

var data;

@override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getData();
}

getData() async{
 var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net', 
 '/mm_api/index.php',{'act':'profile','UsrID': '${UsrID}'}));
  data = jsonDecode(res.body);
  print(data);
  setState(() {});
  print(res.body);
}

 var distnce = double.parse('${data[0]['distance']}');

  double _vlaue = distnce;
  void _setvalue(double vlaue) => setState(() => _vlaue = vlaue,);

  var _distance = " ${(_vlaue * 100).round()} ";

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context){
  

  return Scaffold(
  Container(
     child: Column(
       //padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
       //child: new Center(
       children: [
          Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
             children:[
                Text(
                  'Distance',
                  style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff2c3531),
                  ),
                 ),
                Directionality(
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    child: Text(
                    '${(_vlaue * 100).round()} miles',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff2c3531),
                    ),
                   ),
                  ),
                 ]
                ),
                SizedBox(
                 child: Slider(
                 min:  0,
                 max:  100,
                 value: _vlaue,
                 onChanged: _setvalue,
                 inactiveColor: Color(0xff9a9a9a),
                 activeColor: Color(0xff8f9df2),
                 thumbColor: Color(0xff8f9df2),
                 ),
                 ),
                 Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children:[
                     Text(
                        '1 Miles',
                        style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xff2c3531),
                     ),
                     ),
                     Directionality(
                       textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                          child: Text(
                          '100 Miles',
                          style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xff2c3531),
                           ),
                           ),
                           ),
                         ]
                       ),
                      ],

                     // )
                  ),
                 )
       )
       }
```

Anyone, please help me to understand this error
Here is the error image:- [image: Slider min max value error]

Comment: you should give min and max value for the slider.

Comment: Slider defaults to min 0 and max 1. And the value you have is 17 greater from max value is large. Set the to max property your own value.

Comment: Thank you, I add this min-max value but now I am unable to change the value of the slider. I initialize the values outside the build method. so change the code please see my question I initialize the values outside the build method. but when I initialize the value the `data[0]['distance']` gives me an error which comes from `getData()` and the error is `The instance member 'data' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

```
class EditProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProfile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProfile createState() => _EditProfile();
}

class _EditProfile extends State<EditProfile> {
  var UsrID = Auth.prefs?.getString('usrid');
  var data;

  double distnce = 0;
  double _vlaue = 0;
  String _distance = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _setvalue(double vlaue) => setState(
        () => _vlaue = vlaue,
      );

  getData() async {
    var res = await http.get(Uri.https('www.*******.net',
        '/mm_api/index.php', {'act': 'profile', 'UsrID': '${UsrID}'}));
    data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    distnce = double.parse('${data[0]['distance']}');
    _vlaue = distnce;
    _distance = " ${(_vlaue * 100).round()} ";
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      //padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      //child: new Center(
      children: [
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
          const Text(
            'Distance',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff2c3531),
            ),
          ),
          Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Text(
              '${(_vlaue * 100).round()} miles',
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff2c3531),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
        SizedBox(
          child: Slider(
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            value: _vlaue,
            onChanged: _setvalue,
            inactiveColor: const Color(0xff9a9a9a),
            activeColor: const Color(0xff8f9df2),
            thumbColor: const Color(0xff8f9df2),
          ),
        ),
        Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: const [
          Text(
            '1 Miles',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xff2c3531),
            ),
          ),
          Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Text(
              '100 Miles',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff2c3531),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ],

      // )
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use slider with min and max like this with your business logic

```
Slider(
    value: _vlaue,
    min:  _vlaue - 10,
    max:  _vlaue + 1,
    onChanged: _setvalue,
    inactiveColor: Color(0xff9a9a9a),
    activeColor: Color(0xff8f9df2),
    thumbColor: Color(0xff8f9df2),
)
```

> Note: Always initialize the values outside the build method probably in
> initState. Because when you call setState(), the value will again
> reset since it is inside the build method. So you won't be able to see
> any changes.

Comment: Thank you, I add this min-max value but now I am unable to change the value of the slider. you said that Always initialize the values outside the build method. so change the code please see my question I initialize the values outside the build method. but when I initialize value the `data[0]['distance']` gives me an error which comes from `getData()` and the error is `The instance member 'data' can't be accessed in an initializer.`

Comment: declare the variable outside methods with zeros inside the class and initialize the value in your getData() method before setState.

Comment: added another answer

Comment: how? can you show me.